# USB keyboard switches off in game

Tags: windows-8, usb, keyboard

Out side of games the keyboard works fine and does not turn off.
When I enter a game for example "counter strike : GO" after a few minutes it turns off.

I have tried re-installing the USB root hub. I unchecked allow this computer to turn off this device to save power. It seems I only have 2 USB root hubs though I have three USB ports.

I did go to regedit to give permissions to myself but still did not help.

I am running windows 8. Advent laptop.

Please help!

Comment: Some games have detections for keyboards with unwanted features, like permanent fire and disable them when thinking found such one. There also may be *false positive* detections. Have you tried another keyboard?

Comment: No I have not But I know that it is the USB port. I should have mentioned this but anything that gets plugged into that port in game it turns of just the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is a long shot but maybe tempature is problem. If you have a laptop cooler try with it.

If it helps: Somescewes can be lose. I had a screw at my back panel laptop if it is lose  my keyboard may or may not work.

As i said this is a very long shot so ignore this if you don't have time or cooler.

Comment: the screws I had recently tightened the screws so that would not be the case. cooling I have been playing for a while and it is still cool.